# Scala: Implicit evidence for generic types

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

Assume there are such two traits:

```
trait Fooer[-T] {
  def foo(x: T): Unit
}

trait CanFoo[-T] {
  def fooer: Fooer[T]
}
```

And a function:

```
def bar[T: CanFoo](x: T) = {
  implicitly[CanFoo[T]].fooer.foo(x)
}
```

Everything works so far. However, I was stuck when trying to make `bar` work recursively on collection types like `Seq[T]` (i.e. `bar[Seq[T]](seq)` recursively calls `bar[T]` on `seq`'s elements). I can't do `implicit object CanFooSeq extends CanFoo[Seq[_]]` since that would cause the type information of the elements to be lost. (I also tried to make another function `def bar[T: CanFoo](seq: Seq[T]) = ...`, but that didn't solve the problem either since `Seq[T]` still isn't being recognized as a Foo-able type.)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implicit def CanFooSeq[T]: CanFoo[Seq[T]] = new CanFoo[Seq[T]] { def fooer = ... }
```

(if you want to have it only in case you have `CanFoo[T]`, add the implicit parameter: `implicit def CanFooSeq[T: CanFoo]: CanFoo[Seq[T]] = new CanFoo[Seq[T]] { def fooer = ... }`) if I understood the question correctly. Note it has to be a `def`, because objects and vals can't have type parameters, so a new one will be created on each call (which is very unlikely to matter for performance in practice).

Comment: This gives me `error: '=' expected but 'extends' found.` Any idea?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know `def`s can be used here. Very helpful solution!